# How to use Modernizr classes?

Tags: css, cross-browser, modernizr

I am new to modernizr. I read some documentation on modernizr, and  I wanted to set `border: none` if browser doesn't support CSS3 `box-sizing: border-box`. I tried:

```
li { border-right: 1px solid #eee }
.css-boxsizing li { border: none }
```

But it didnt work out. Can any1 suggest something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Modernizr, supported features are added as a class name to the root element. After inspecting the list of classes at http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/test/, I've found the correct class name to be **`boxsizing`**:

```
.boxsizing li { border: none }
```

In the [default build](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/modernizr.js), the `boxsizing` class seems not to be added. This can manually be [added](https://raw.github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/master/feature-detects/css-boxsizing.js) using [`Modernizr.addTest`](http://modernizr.com/docs/#addtest):

```
// The first argument is the class name
Modernizr.addTest("boxsizing", function() {
    return Modernizr.testAllProps("boxSizing") && (document.documentMode === undefined || document.documentMode > 7);
});​​​​​​
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjwZ/

Comment: box-sizing is now part of non-core extras:  https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/248  https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css-boxsizing.js