# How do I detect box-sizing border-box support with Modernizr

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

I have boxes that do not display correctly in Firefox 16 and below, it seems to be a lack of support for box sizing border box.

How can I detect box sizing border box support with Modernizr and treat the css differently for browsers that do not support it?

Comment: Are you including the `-moz` prefix? It [should work fine](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing) in FF 16 and below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modernizr does not include the box sizing test in their default build. It's one of their core extras.

Check out this:

[How to use Modernizr classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057660/how-to-use-modernizr-classes)

I think it has what you are looking for:

```
// The first argument is the class name
Modernizr.addTest("boxsizing", function() {
    return Modernizr.testAllProps("boxSizing") && (document.documentMode === undefined       
|| document.documentMode > 7);
});​​​​​​
```

Comment: This polyfill might also be of interest: [boxsizing.htc](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill)

Comment: Thank you Bolt and Nils. I'll look into these solutions and see if I can get one of them to work.

Comment: Cool. Come back and tag it please if it does so I can get some more rep on here :-)